# Django, some logs are not logged when using Celery

Tags: django, logging, sentry

I'm seeing where I can see

`logger.exception("hello")` is executed.

But nothing is logged on sentry or file.

I have settings concerning logs as below

```
LOGGING = {
     'version': 1,
     'disable_existing_loggers': True,
     'filters': {
         'require_debug_false': {
             '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
         }
     },
     'formatters': {
         'verbose': {
             'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s (%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d) %(message)s'
         },
         'simple': {
             'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
         },
     },
     'handlers': {
         'null': {
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
         },
         # Send all messages to console
         'console': {
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
             'formatter': 'verbose'
         },
         # Warning messages are sent to admin emails
         'mail_admins': {
             'level': 'WARNING',
             'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
             'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
         },
         # critical errors are logged to sentry
         'sentry': {
             'level': 'INFO',
             'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
         },
     },
     'loggers': {
         # This is the "catch all" logger
         '': {
             'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'propagate': False,
         },

         'django.db.backends': {
             'handlers': ['null'],  # Quiet by default!
             'propagate': False,
             'level': 'DEBUG',
         },
     }
  }
```

And I log stuff with

```
 import logging
 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

 logger.exception("error")
 logger.info({"error": "foo"})
```

Why am I losing some of logs?
(I've followed the code in debugger and log was executed but nothing in sentry/log file)..

Comment: What's the value of the `DEBUG` setting?

Comment: I tried both False and True, same result.

Comment: Are you using celery in this project by any chance?

Comment: @solarissmoke ah yes, I found some logs are hidden inside celery log file (not sent to sentry), but the ones I'm missing is not celery related

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by celery, which [hijacks the root (`''`) logger by default](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-hijack-root-logger) and discards any previously configured root logger. That means your configuration gets ignored.

Try adding this setting:

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

Comment: oh! hope it works!. btw, it seems all the previously ignored(?) celery logs are logged. Can I keep root logger and disable the celery logs?

Comment: You can set a higher `--loglevel` on the worker I guess.